# Список проголосовавших - баг или фича?

Tags: поддержка

Вот интересен такой момент, допустим проголосовали за `закрытие` или `оставить открытым`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
После чего если нажать `back` в браузера то получим такую инфу
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вроде как такое поведение заметил только сегодня, хотя могу и ошибаться...так это нормальное поведение и такую статистику может можно видеть в какой нить вкладке о которой я не знаю?

Comment: Доступен только когда сами проголосуете, так что субъективности не добавляет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это нормальное поведение. Результаты всех проверок общедоступны и обсуждаемы  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tools/suggested-edits .

Comment: общедоступны после 2К кармы как я понял?

Comment: @ermak0ff Сводные таблицы типа той, что в этом ответе, требуют некоторой репутации. Транскрипт проверки конкретного вопроса/ответа доступен всем, даже анонимным пользователям -- если у них есть ссылка такая как http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/32430

Comment: воо, этого и не знал,  спасибо

Comment: @ermak0ff в том числе автор проверяемого сообщения может это видеть.